# How do I list all of a user's roles in snowflake DB?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is it possible to list all of the roles that a user has access to in Snowflake DB?

I seem to be able to show the users with access to a role but I can't figure out how to list the roles a user is granted.  Of course I can crawl the roles and work at it from that angle, but it would be very beneficial to do the opposite.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turns out that:

```
show grants to user <user-name>;
```

actually lists the roles of the user. I had tried this before and misread the output and ended up wasting a lot of time looking for alternatives.

Comment: Thank you, this took a bit longer to figure out than I'd expected.

Comment: Yeah; you're not the only one :).

Comment: This command does not list ALL the roles assigned to the user. It will especially not list the inherited roles.

Comment: You can also use the [`database.information_schema`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/info-schema.html) table for this but as Chadwick noted, it will not list the nested roles by default with a `where user=<username>` clause.  You'll need to figure out the maximum depth of your roles tree and execute nested queries against that until you reach the bottom.